# Reliable Redis cache TTL expiration hook

Tags: azure-redis-cache, redis-cache

Does Azure Redis cache allow me to set a function to reliably trigger whenever a certain key in my cache expires?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can combine a client using [Redis Pub/Sub](https://redis.io/topics/pubsub) and [Redis Keyspace Notifications](https://redis.io/topics/notifications) to have a client receive a message when events happen to specific keys, or when specific events happen to any key. You can then use [pattern-matching subscriptions](https://redis.io/topics/pubsub#pattern-matching-subscriptions) to receive messages for more than a single key. You can also subscribe to multiple channels from a single client; all messages include which channel it is publishing to so your client can decide what to do.

To receive a message when any key beginning with `foo` expires, do the following:

1. Set `notify-keyspace-events` config value to `Kx` using the Azure Portal. Steps to set value for Azure are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-configure#keyspace-notifications-advanced-settings). More details on the config value schema are defined [here](https://redis.io/topics/notifications#configuration).
2. Using the client of your choice, [PSUBSCRIBE](https://redis.io/commands/psubscribe) (pattern subscribe) to the channel for your key: `PSUBSCRIBE '__keyspace@*__:foo*'`
3. Using another client connection, set a value for your key with a TTL: `SET foo42 bar EX 5`
4. After 5 seconds, you should see a message on your subscribing client: `"pmessage","__keyspace@*__:foo*","__keyspace@0__:foo42","expired"`

To receive a message when any key expires, do the following:

1. Set `notify-keyspace-events` config value to `Ex`
2. PSUBSCRIBE to the keyevent channel for keys being expired: `PSUBSCRIBE '__keyevent@*__:expired'`
3. In another client, set a key with a TTL: `SET foo bar EX 5`
4. After 5 seconds, see a message on your subscribing client: `"pmessage","__keyevent@*__:expired","__keyevent@0__:expired","foo"`

For clients to quickly develop and debug, I would recommend using [redis-cli](https://redis.io/topics/rediscli) or the [Redis console in the Azure Portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-configure#redis-console).

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, is it possible to get the content of the Key ? like "bar" in your example, I can't find a way to access the content

Comment: I don't think so since Redis server would have already been removed the keys by the time it sends the notification.